# How could I call a custom function within a QUERY formula on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

Would it be something like this?

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/fsdgsgsdhdshldhsdhgvs/edit","Reference Info!A2:J"),"select * where Col2 matches '"&fileName()&"'")
```

Here is the `fileName()` function:

```
//Since I'm not sure fileName() will run as the recalculations happen, I've added this one
function onOpen(){
fileName();
}

function fileName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is fine, but it doesn't make sense to have

```
function onOpen(){
fileName();
}
```

as custom functions are executed when the spreadsheet is opened and when the custom function arguments change.

Related

- [Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17341399/1595451)
- [get sheet names not work properly or not auto update after use loop to copy to new sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60471654/1595451)